# How is the OneTrust SDK installed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, third-party-cookies, one-trust

I am trying to run the following line of code

```
  OneTrust.OnConsentChanged(() => {
        alert("consent changed");
    });
```

As expected, I am getting the error message: `'OneTrust' is not defined.`

However I cannot find anywhere in the OneTrust docs that explain how to import the OneTrust object.

The function above is found in [these docs](https://community.cookiepro.com/s/article/UUID-d8291f61-aa31-813a-ef16-3f6dec73d643?language=en_US).

Please could someone explain how to import the OneTrust object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
window.OneTrust.OnConsentChanged(() => {
        alert("consent changed");
    });
```

SDK starting to be available after the scripts of OneTrust were loaded inside `<head>` tag as :

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx" src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">function OptanonWrapper() {}</script>
// rest of the elements inside head tag
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was my solution in the end, however as I was implementing this into a BigCommerce store, I added this code to the scripts within the BigCommerce admin panel.